# Libgdx velocity with angle

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, velocity, angle

I'm having a gun which moves with the player and its position and angle keeps changing as the player moves. I have got the rotation angle of the gun with me and I put that in `setAngularVelocity` but nothing happens. Do I have to do something in the update method ?

```
public Shot(float x, float y, float a) {
    setBody(); // Made a KinematicBody body here
    setSprite();
    body.setLinearVelocity(12f, 0);
    body.setAngularVelocity(a); // a = gun.getAngle();
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that angular velocity is how fast something is rotating?

Comment: `body.setLinearVelocity(MyGame.SHOT_SPEED * MathUtils.cos(a), MyGame.SHOT_SPEED * MathUtils.sin(a));` solved it!